# How to display a text property in a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a month class

```
public class Month
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // ex: 1
    public string Name { get; set; } // ex: January
    public string ShortName { get; set; } // ex: JAN
```

It's bound to my view model

```
    public List<SelectListItem> Months { get; set; }
    public int SelectedMonth { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MonthItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(Months, "Id"); }
    }
```

Here is my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMonth, Model.Months)
```

The drop down list displays only the ID. How can I get it to show the month's Name property, but still "link" to the ID.

I've seen other examples use something like this...

```
@Html.DropDownList("Month",
    Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = i.ToString(),
        Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)
    }))
```

...but the thing is that I only want the months showing up that actually have data to the year selected in another drop down list. I have this query already built. Point is, I can't just autopopulate the dropdown with all months because some months "don't exist"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code you posted at the end, just with your list of applicable months instead of the `Enumerable.Range(1, 12)` part. To get that list, you can use `GroupBy` on your dataset. You didn't post your model for me to work with, but generally, that would look something like:

```
var months = dataset.GroupBy(g => g.DateProperty.Month).Select(m => m.Key);
```

Then:

```
months.Select(i => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = i.ToString(),
    Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)
}))
```

When you run the group by, you'll end up with a list of lists, where each list is keyed to an integer representing the month of the items in that list. Importantly, this will only contain months that were found in your dataset, naturally excluding ones that aren't represented. Then, you just select out the keys to get an enumerable of just the month integers. I'm not sure how you're currently getting your list of available years, but the same procedure can be used there as well.